# Как в цикле запросить у пользователя ввод данных и остановить выполнение JavaScript программы до нажатия enter? Prompt не предлагать

Tags: javascript

Такая задача.
Есть блок div.
Нужен javaScript, который будет делать следующее:

1. В цикле вставлять input-ы в div по одному;
2. Вставив 1 input, программа ждёт ввода в него значения (можно пустое) и нажатия Enter (это как prompt, только без диалогового окна);
3. По нажатию Enter значение input-а сохраняется в переменную, выводится alert со значением;
4. Цикл повторяется (появляется следующий input).

Вот заготовка:

```
<div class="my_div">
  <!-- сюда будут вставляться input-ы -->
</div>


<script>
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".my_div").append("<input type='text' id='field_for_answer' autofocus/>");

//  здесь программа останавливается, ждет ввода значения и нажатия Enter в input

  var yourAnswer = document.getElementById("field_for_answer").value;
  alert("Вы ввели: " + yourAnswer);
  }

  alert ("Цикл закончился!")
</script>
```

Второй день рыщу по сети в поисках решения. Я так понимаю, здесь в главном цикле должен быть ещё цикл :

```
while (пока не нажмёшь Enter ) {
  показывать input;
}
```

Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: на самом деле тут циклы вообще не нужны

Comment: @Grundy, очень содержательный ответ

Answer (score 1):

После долгих совещаний получайте рабочий пример, без циклов) Спасибо @Grundy за разъяснения

```js
var append = function(i) {
  $(".my_div").append("<input type='text' id='" + i + "' class='field_for_answer' autofocus/>");
};
var i = 1;
append(i);
$('.my_div').on('keyup', '.field_for_answer:last-child', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 && i < 10) {
    i++;
    append(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='my_div'></div>
```

Comment: будет работать только для первого инпута, так как на остальные не навешивается обработчик события

Comment: тоже так подумал, наверно нужно будет каждый раз определять последний дочерний элемент класса

Comment: не угадал. у тебя `$('.field_for_answer').keyup` вызывается **один** раз, когда у тебя есть только **один** элемент с этим классом. Для решения надо либо использовать делегирование, навешивая событие на `".my_div"` с параметром `.field_for_answer` в методе `on`, либо навешивать событие при создании инпута

Comment: @Grundy, всё равно не понимаю,  по логике `.keyup()` срабатывает каждый раз при нажатии клавиш в **последнем** инпуте определяемый  `.field_for_answer:last-child`, остальные инпуты не должны срабатывать для вызова этой функции. Просто дописывать в инпут при создании `onkeyup="myFunction()"` как то не солидно.

Comment: событие добавляется каждому элементу в выбранном наборе: в твоем случае это первый элемент добавленный append. Других элементов нет в это время. Поэтому после их создания и добавления обработчик на них срабатывать не будет. дописывать onkeyup  не обязательно: можно просто перенести `$('...').keyup` **внутрь** append, либо воспользоваться делегированием. Посмотри примеры использования метода `on`

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, до меня дошло, можно использовать `$(document).on('keyup', '.field_for_answer:last-child', function(){});` и это будет работать

Comment: `:last-child` не нужен, и рекомендуют ставить обработчик на ближайшего родителя, а не документ

Answer (score 0):

Чем не устраивают модальные окна на html/css/js? Поставить такое окно, закрытие этого окна ТОЛЬКО если нажата кнопка ЭНТЕР и есть какой-то текст в инпуте, скрыть модальное окно. Сохранение и обработку данных из инпута модального окно - jquery